# Melf's Acid Arrow and Bonus damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, meldshaping

Due to some *Lucky Dice* (the soulmeld) from *Magic of Incarnum* book, I am getting +1 generic bonus damage (a luck bonus).

This seems to quite clearly apply to the initial damage of Acid Arrow, but how does this work with the repeating acid damage?

1. The repeating damage is not augmented at all.
2. The repeating damage is augmented with the *Lucky Dice* bonus the caster had when the spell was cast.
3. The repeating damage updates its damage bonus to the caster's current *Lucky Dice* bonus, every round.

Comment: Where is your Dice from? The one I've read about was only able to provide +1 bonus, I think. So what's the book it is in?

Comment: @Mołot If essentia is invested in it, it becomes a rolling bonus turn over turn up to a maximum of the essentia invested :)

Comment: (I, too, wish it worked that way, but the soulmeld *lucky dice* is only ever grants a +1 luck bonus. Invested essentia just lengthens the soulmeld's effect's duration. The question remains a valid one, though.)

Comment: Where in *Complete Scoundrel*? (My cursory search was fruitless.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Apologies, I quickly checked to make sure myself and I had actually misread that piece! I will adjust the question for it (and apologise to my DM)

Comment: Darn! I was hoping you'd found something I'd missed! `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't argue question is invalid, I just wanna know what book OP is using, to make sure I'm reading the same Lucky Dice he is reading. Weckar, I see you updated your question, but could you add book info none the less?

Comment: @Mołot Magic of Incarnum. I was wrong in how the Dice worked, but the question remains valid.

Comment: @Mołot I am not sure how relevant the addition is, as I don't believe any soulmelds were printed outside of this book?

Comment: I believe it does not hurt, makes search faster (for example for users searching for Incarnum questions here) and clarifies you are not using any 3rd party version in case of doubt. Given that Stack Exchange aims (or aimed, at least) to create a knowledge base, search seems to be important reason on its own.

Comment: (Unlike *Tome of Battle*, there are a handful more soulmelds in *Dragon* #350 and *Dragon Magic* and on the Wizards Web site.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan There actually **are** a few non-*Tome of Battle* books that use (but don’t add to) *Tome of Battle* material. *Monster Manual IV* or *V*, IIRC, has something with Favored Class: Crusader, and *Dragons of Eberron* has the war wyrm sovereign archetype, which trades away some sorcerer spells for some warblade maneuvers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each swift action you use to activate *lucky dice*, you can gain a +1 bonus to damage rolls made before the beginning of your next turn. That includes the damage roll you make for *acid arrow*’s lingering damage. So the answer to your question is 3, each damage roll receives a bonus based on *lucky dice* at the time it was rolled. You don’t get to “bake in” the *lucky dice* bonus, extending it for the duration of your *acid arrow* spell, but you do get the bonus.

Please note that *acid arrow* is a pretty weak spell, and *lucky dice* are a **very** weak soulmeld. Neither comes recommended.

Comment: I am aware they are not ideal picks. Having banned Evocation and Abjuration, I needed some 2nd level spells to give me direct options in combat - and acid is a generally good damage type. It's also a Reserves of Strength build, so it is guaranteed to keep growing with me.

Comment: O, the soulmeld's not *that* bad. If, in a low-level build, a player's considering Weapon Focus solely for the bonus to attack rolls, I recommend instead Shape Soulmeld (*lucky dice*) as a superior alternative… then I point them at Law Devotion or Chaos Devotion.

Comment: @HeyICanChan It is not ACTUALLY superior if they have better things to do with their Swift Actions. But the player in question (I get the bonus through a chakra bind but that should not matter) has this thing for dice-and-gambling flavored abilities.

Comment: @HeyICanChan No one should consider Weapon Focus for its own benefit anyway; it is also “**very** weak.” But at least Weapon Focus opens up a lot of options that use it as a prerequisite. And swift actions have some value.

Comment: @WeckarE. I strongly recommend *glitterdust* for that slot. You don’t need to be more direct than that. (Also, Reserves of Strength doesn’t really matter to *acid arrow*, since its cap isn’t until 18th anyway.)

Comment: In a group where lv 9 Wizards regularly walk around with a CL of 30... yeah it matters. :P

Comment: @WeckarE. The low-level warrior, though, often *doesn't* have anything better to do with his swift actions, and an +1 bonus at-will on attack and damage *or* on saving throws *or* on skill and ability checks—while that +1 still matters—is okay-ish. (This DM also allows feat retraining from *PH2*, so changing out the feat when it's no longer useful is a thing.)